# Speed up Google Web App Spreadsheet loading

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a GAS Web App that reads a spreadsheet (it is not associated with the spreadsheet, and can't be for unrelated reasons).

I load in the sheet, or a range thereof, like this:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Projects');
var data = dataSheet.getRange('A1:BL').getValues();
```

I've done a lot of testing, and with my lightly-populated A1:BL5500 spreadsheet (with a fair number of cells filled with a few dozen characters of text), the load time takes around 6 seconds. I've tried named ranges and lots of things, but can't get it faster than that.

What I really need is 1 column of the sheet, then I do a search to find the row I need, and then I need that row. But loading the 1 column takes nearly the same amount of time as loading the entire thing. Is there a better way to do this? The delay is problematic.

Here's the timing breakdown:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid) [0.174 seconds]
Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Projects]) [0 seconds]
Sheet.getRange([A1:BL]) [0.387 seconds]
Range.getValues() [6.483 seconds]
```

For comparison, here's loading just one column:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid) [0.164 seconds]
Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Projects]) [0 seconds]
Sheet.getRange([A1:A]) [0.336 seconds]
Range.getValues() [5.887 seconds]
```

These are just single runs, the time differences aren't significant (they vary).

Comment: I have got a work-around: I've created a new sheet, one column of which equals the column I need to search on. I load that. When I complete my search, I load only the relevant row from the full sheet. It takes the total time from around 8 seconds to around 2, which might be acceptable.

Comment: Please add this solution as an answer.

Comment: I also found that parsing the published csv of ss to be much faster.

Comment: Tom Woodward: this is a pretty active environment, I don't think that could work here (sheet is being changed all the time). Also, the csv would be quite large I think. Interesting thought though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted above, I found one answer that might be helpful to others.
I created a second sheet ("ProjectIndex"), and set up two columns that merely pointed to the corresponding columns of interest in "Projects" (I'd originally said I was just searching one column, to keep it simpler: I'm actually searching two).
I load that data, find the row of interest, and go back to "Projects" and load only the row I want.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('ProjectIndex');
var data = dataSheet.getRange('A1:B').getValues();

... // search data and find row i

var j = i+1; // account for zero-based array but 1-based row numbering
var rc = 'A'+j+':BL'+j; // there are BL columns in Projects
var record = ss.getSheetByName('Projects').getRange(rc).getValues();
```

Time to load ProjectIndex:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid) [0.153 seconds]
Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([ProjectIndex]) [0 seconds]
Sheet.getRange([A1:B]) [0.282 seconds]
Range.getValues() [0.504 seconds]
```

Time to load one row of Projects:

```
Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Projects]) [0 seconds]
Sheet.getRange([A4785:BL4785]) [0.513 seconds]
Range.getValues() [0.352 seconds]
```

I purposely illustrated with a row near the bottom of the file. It may be that I could load ProjectIndex asynchronously earlier, I don't know if that would further speed things up and I don't know how to do it anyway. Subsequent searches can in principle be fast, except for being uncertain about whether the data is up to date.